# Applying FFT in real time for accelerometer

Tags: android, fft, accelerometer

I need some help in apply FFT to android accelerometer data.
here is the code for the FFT that I found:

```
public class FFT {

  int n, m;

  // Lookup tables. Only need to recompute when size of FFT changes.
  double[] cos;
  double[] sin;

  public FFT(int n) {
      this.n = n;
      this.m = (int) (Math.log(n) / Math.log(2));

      // Make sure n is a power of 2
      if (n != (1 << m))
          throw new RuntimeException("FFT length must be power of 2");

      // precompute tables
      cos = new double[n / 2];
      sin = new double[n / 2];

      for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
          cos[i] = Math.cos(-2 * Math.PI * i / n);
          sin[i] = Math.sin(-2 * Math.PI * i / n);
      }

  }

  public void fft(double[] x, double[] y) {
      int i, j, k, n1, n2, a;
      double c, s, t1, t2;

      // Bit-reverse
      j = 0;
      n2 = n / 2;
      for (i = 1; i < n - 1; i++) {
          n1 = n2;
          while (j >= n1) {
              j = j - n1;
              n1 = n1 / 2;
          }
          j = j + n1;

          if (i < j) {
              t1 = x[i];
              x[i] = x[j];
              x[j] = t1;
              t1 = y[i];
              y[i] = y[j];
              y[j] = t1;
          }
      }

      // FFT
      n1 = 0;
      n2 = 1;

      for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
          n1 = n2;
          n2 = n2 + n2;
          a = 0;

          for (j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
              c = cos[a];
              s = sin[a];
              a += 1 << (m - i - 1);

              for (k = j; k < n; k = k + n2) {
                  t1 = c * x[k + n1] - s * y[k + n1];
                  t2 = s * x[k + n1] + c * y[k + n1];
                  x[k + n1] = x[k] - t1;
                  y[k + n1] = y[k] - t2;
                  x[k] = x[k] + t1;
                  y[k] = y[k] + t2;
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

In the onSensorChanged I apply a low pass filter to the sensor data with this:

```
private float[] filter(float[] input, float[] output)
{
    if ( output == null ) return input;     
    for ( int i=0; i<input.length; i++ ) {
        output[i] = output[i] + ALPHA * (input[i] - output[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

And then use it here

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se) 
{
    if (se.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    {
        accelData = filter(se.values.clone(),accelData);
        accelMag = (float) Math.sqrt(accelData[0]*accelData[0] + accelData[1]*accelData[1] + accelData[2]*accelData[2]); 

        //apply fft to accelMag here. accelFFT = ...                    
    }
}
```

Everything that I searched online was for using an FFT for precomputed data, but I couldn't find how to do it in real time like in this example.

Thanks

Comment: Just collect your samples and save them in an array, to build your *precomputed* data.

Comment: I'm using this for a step counter so I need the information immediately, how would I do that without delaying the functions needed for counting the steps?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to achieve with the FFT? Is it for filtering the signal, do you want to detect some frequencies, what is your basis to expect (relatively stable) oscillations (of several periods) in the input data?